# get the position of the mouse relative to the size of the react element (React)

Tags: reactjs, mouse-position

is it possible to get the mouse position relative to the size of the element (div, img) in the react?

I already tried this

```
 _onMouseMove(e) {
  const position = this.refs.elem.getDOMNode().getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(position, e.nativeEvent.offsetX, e.screenX);

  this.setState({
    x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX,
    y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY
   });
  }
```

Comment: Some more info would be helpful; can you describe the result of your current code vs. what you'd like to happen?

Comment: You can make code snippets runnable (or link to a codepen) - also what do you mean by relative to the size? distance from the bounding box?

Comment: I have a system that I use to draw a line in SVG, using react, and I have a problem when I draw the line each one does not follow exactly the mouse pointv   --- code below

Answer (score 0):

```html
    import React from 'react';

var activeMouse1 = false;
var activeMouse = false;
var posX1;
var posY2;

var pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);

    this.MouseDown = this.MouseDown.bind(this);

    this.state = { x: 0,
         y: 0,
         x1: 100,
         y1: 100,
         list:[],
         drawingLine:undefined,
        };




  }

  handleMouseClick1(){
    activeMouse1 = true;
  }

  handleMouseClick(){
    activeMouse = true;
  }


  handleMouseDown(){
    activeMouse1 = false;
    activeMouse = false;
  }


  handleMouseMove(event) {

    if (this.state.drawingLine){
      const drawingLine = this.state.drawingLine;

      drawingLine.x2 = event.screenX /2.7;
      drawingLine.y2 = event.screenY /3.8;

      this.setState({drawingLine:drawingLine});

      return;
    }

  /*  if(activeMouse1 == true){
      this.setState({
        x: event.pageX /2.7,
        y: event.pageY /3.8
      });
      posX1 = event.clientX /1.5;
      posY2 = event.clientY /3.8;
    }

    if(activeMouse == true){
      this.setState({
        x1: event.clientX /2.7,
        y1: event.clientY /3.8
      });

    }*/

  }

    MouseDown(event){
          console.log("x ", event.screenX /2.7)
          console.log("y ", event.screenY /3.8)


          pos3 = event.screenX /2.7;
          pos4 = event.screenY /3.8;

          this.newLine = {x1:pos3,y1:pos4,x2:0,y2:0};

          if (this.state.drawingLine){
            const list = this.state.list;

            list.push(this.state.drawingLine);
            this.setState({list:list,drawingLine:undefined});
          }else{
            this.setState({drawingLine:{
              x1:pos3,
              y1:pos4
            }})
          }

    }





  render() {


    return (
      <div style={{ height: '100%', background:"green" }}  >



        <svg onMouseDown={this.MouseDown} onMouseUp={this.MouseUp}  onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                       xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500"
                           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

                  {this.state.list.map((line,i)=>
                    <line x1={line.x1} y1={line.y1} x2={line.x2} y2={line.y2} strokeWidth="2.5" stroke="#cccccc"/>
                  )}

                  {this.state.drawingLine && this.state.drawingLine.x2 && this.state.drawingLine.y2
                  ? <line x1={this.state.drawingLine.x1} y1={this.state.drawingLine.y1} x2={this.state.drawingLine.x2} y2={this.state.drawingLine.y2 }
                     strokeWidth="2.5" stroke="#cccccc"/>
                  :undefined}
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: the code will not work for lack of library, it's just to show what I did